# How to save key value pairs in Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, keyvaluepair

I am building an app that allows users to name colors. For example, users can name #00FFFF as "green". I need to store these names and the corresponding colors in Core Data.

I think the best way to do it is to save the pairs as key-value pairs - the color as the key, and the names as values. But when I created a new entity and added the two attributes, I don't have a way to tell Core Data that the color is the "primary key" or something. And I can't tell Core Data to get me the corresponding names.

I have thought of some workarounds but they are not "swifty" enough.

1. Save the key-value pairs as a dictionary in `NSUserDefaults`. But I can only save `[String: AnyObject]` in there. What I need is `[Int: String]`. I know that I can convert ints to strings, but that just makes the code more unreadable and un-swifty. Also, I need to cast the value for the key from an `AnyObject` to `String`, which is another thing that I don't like. It's like generics have not been invented.
2. I can save the color and the name in a Core Data entity. When I want to find what's the corresponding name for a color, I linear search through the whole thing.

Like this:

```
for item in allTheColorNames {
    if item.color == theStuffIWantToFind {
        // do something
        break
    }
}
```

I wish I could do it in one go. The above code is not very elegant, you know what I mean?

Is there a way to store the color-name pairs in Core Data so that I can do something like this?

```
var theNameOfGreen = colorNameDictionary[0x00ff00]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Dmytro recommends, should be the correct way to do it in Core Data.
I would argue though that it creates a lot of overhead for something that could be very easy. Why not save it in a property list? Just create one in Xcode, add a dictionary, and have the names a key, and the corresponding color as value.

To load a dictionary from a plist file:

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
let documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0)as NSString
let path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("MyFile.plist")

let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

// Check if file exists
if(!fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path))
{
    // If it doesn't, copy it from the default file in the Resources folder
    let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("DefaultFile", ofType: "plist")
    fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundle, toPath: path, error:nil)
}

var data = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path)
```

To save a dictionary to a plist file:

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
let documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0) as NSString
let path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("MyFile.plist")

data.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
```

Comment: Hmm... Seems like a pretty good idea to use plists in this situation. But I can't quite understand your code. But thanks for the idea anyways! I will do some more research on plists!

Comment: I just noticed I switched the loading and saving around. It's actually quite simple. You take a dictionary which you save in the documentDirectory as a plist. When starting up your app or whenever you need it you load the data. 

When your app gets closed, you can write to this file from the dictionary. Half of the code concerns the correctly setting of the file path :)

Answer (score -1):

You need use "Relationships",  one-to-one i guess.

Create a new entity "NamesForColors" and add 1 attribute "name"(for example), and 1 relationship "color"(for example).

Then create second "Colors" entity and add 1 attribute "color"(for example), and 1 relationship "name"(for example).
And bind them.

If I understand you correctly.

Comment: Core Data don't have concept like "primary key". Only NSManagedObjectID as a unique id.